# Вызвать сигнал pressed() для QDialogButtonBox

Tags: c++, qt, сигналы-слоты

Через дизайнер была создана форма, а на ней, по умолчанию, образовался QDialogButtonBox с Ok и Cancel. Для них система создала соответственно сигналы и слоты
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 

Оба слота в итоге закроют окно. Да и сигналы эти передаются, когда кнопка уже отпущена.
А мне бы хотелось, не закрывать окно, если пользователь ввёл что-то не так, а мог сразу же исправить.
Значит, мне нужен сигнал pressed() (от QAbstractButton). Но вот незадача, такого у QDialogButtonBox нет!
Поговаривают, что можно обратится к кнопке из бокса как-то так

```
// in dialog contructor:
connect(ui->buttonBox->button(QDialogButtonBox::Reset), SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(on_reset_clicked())
```

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/56986-intercepting-button-clicks-in-QDialogButtonBox?s=9e86359900b2d6a05b6fd969da14ae17&p=280861#post280861

Но у меня видит только "ButtonRole", а не кнопки. Следовательно вообще никаких сигналов нет.

ПыСы: да, можно создать просто две кнопки и накинуть на них сигналы-слоты по-простому, но это же слишком просто! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам не нужен сигнал `pressed`. При закрытии диалогового окна у него вызывается метод [QDialog::closeEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#closeEvent). Переопределите этот метод и в нём проверяйте правильность ввода. Если ввод неправильный, то вызовите метод [QEvent::ignore](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#ignore). Примерно так:

```
void MyDialog::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *e)
{
    //здесь проверьте ваш ввод
    if (ввод неправильный)
        e->ignore();
}
```